# Expression for f(x) as a function of g(x)

Tags: limits, solution-verification

> (b) Set g(x) = f(x)  +   (1/|f(x)|) for every 0 < |x−c| < δ. Find an
> expression for f(x) as a function of g(x) for every 0 < |x − c| < δ.

We haven't really gone over this topic in class, and I can't seem to figure out what does it mean to find an expression for f(x) s a function of g(x)..

Answer (score 0):

$g(x) = \dfrac{f(x) + 1}{f(x)}$

$g(x) \cdot f(x) = f(x) + 1$

$(g(x) - 1) \cdot f(x) = 1$

$f(x) = \dfrac{1}{g(x)-1}$

I guess that's how it's supposed to be solved

Comment: Sorry I eddited the question and made it cleared. The way you did it just doesnt seem to work for me..

Comment: In order for user786878 or anyone else to respond here, more information is needed.  Could you be **much more precise** re "The way you did it just doesnt seem to work for me"?  For example, is there a specific step in user786878's answer that you don't understand, or question the validity of?

Comment: I edited the question to make it more clear, user was solving a different question..